# Renaming list elements after moving some of its items in XSLT 1.0.

Tags: sorting, xslt, dynamic

I have this xml:

```
 <Process>
          <elem0>
             <pcode>xx<pcode>
          </elem0>
          <elem1>
             <pcode>xy<pcode>
          </elem1>
          <elem2>
             <pcode>ab<pcode>
          </elem2>
          <elem3>
             <pcode>AD<pcode>
          </elem3>               
    </Process>
```

And I have to MOVE elements with pcode value='xy' to  EdProcess, which I am doing it successfully with xslt.  Also, I got the Process elements to show up in order with the help from fellow members here. Now the issue is, EdProcess needs to start at elem0, and any new elements that gets moved inside of it should be in order, i.e elem0, elem1, elem2, etc.

```
<Process>
      <elem0>
         <pcode>xx<pcode>
      </elem0>
      <elem1>
         <pcode>ab<pcode>
      </elem1>
      <elem2>
         <pcode>AD<pcode>
      </elem2>               
</Process>



<EdProcess>
          <elem1>
             <pcode>xy<pcode>
          </elem1>
   </EdProcess>
```

I would like for it to be

```
<Process>
          <elem0>
             <pcode>xx<pcode>
          </elem0>
          <elem1>
             <pcode>ab<pcode>
          </elem1>
          <elem2>
             <pcode>AD<pcode>
          </elem2>               
    </Process>

 <EdProcess>
          <elem0>
             <pcode>xy<pcode>
          </elem0>
   </EdProcess>
```

so it shows up properly in front end, but I am stuck. Tried sorting but didn't work. elem identifications are changing so it is harder for me to use a template of some sort. Since I am createing EdProcess, template matching is not working. Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a small modification to my answer to your previous question:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <root>
      <Process>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[pcode != 'xy']" mode="elems" />
      </Process>
      <EdProcess>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[pcode = 'xy']" mode="elems" />
      </EdProcess>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="elems">
    <xsl:element name="elem{position() - 1}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run on the following input:

```
<Process>
  <elem0>
    <pcode>xx</pcode>
  </elem0>
  <elem1>
    <pcode>xy</pcode>
  </elem1>
  <elem2>
    <pcode>ab</pcode>
  </elem2>
  <elem3>
    <pcode>xy</pcode>
  </elem3>
  <elem4>
    <pcode>AD</pcode>
  </elem4>
</Process>
```

The result is:

```
<root>
  <Process>
    <elem0>
      <pcode>xx</pcode>
    </elem0>
    <elem1>
      <pcode>ab</pcode>
    </elem1>
    <elem2>
      <pcode>AD</pcode>
    </elem2>
  </Process>
  <EdProcess>
    <elem0>
      <pcode>xy</pcode>
    </elem0>
    <elem1>
      <pcode>xy</pcode>
    </elem1>
  </EdProcess>
</root>
```